# Retrieve all deployed process definitions through REST in jBPM

Tags: java, jbpm

in jBPM 6.1 the REST call "../rest/deployment/processes" returns a list containing all process definitions deployed; is this deprecated in jBPM 6.2? is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, I created https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPM-4578